# Wix3.8 WixUI_Advanced dialog how to skip license agreement

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7, wix3.8

I am using wix3.8 and in my install MSI, i need InstallScopeDlg which is only available using WixUI_Advanced, however I do not the first dialog which is the license agreement.

I have seen a lot of posts on how to skip (or not display) that dialog BUT they are all using WixUI_InstallDir which does not support InstallScopeDlg.

This is what I have:

```
<Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="Outlook Add In" />
<Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />

<UI Id="UiSequence">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
</UI>
```

Can anyone please show me how to hide or skip the license agreement while still using WixUI_Advanced.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that the way Windows Installer flows from dialog to dialog is through the use of [NewDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [ControlEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Basically Dialog 1 will have a Next [PushButton Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a NewDialog Control Event that says goto dialog 2.  Dialog 2 will then have a Back Button that says go to Dialog 1.  The WiX UI extension hides all this from you in an attempt to make it easy to create a basic UI.  However, you can see it if you edit the built MSI using ORCA and look at the [ControlEvent table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The ControlEvent table has an Ordering column. The MSDN doco doesn't really explain this correctly but it's not really an order so much as it is a priority.  Highest that evaluates to true wins.

In WiX, the [Publish element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/publish.html) corresponds to ControlEvent entries. The trick is to author NewDialog control events on the correct controls to out rank the existing entries and bypass the undesired dialog or to insert a new dialog.

An example of how to do this can be found [here](http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Application/IsWiXAddIn/MSISolutionTemplate/SetupProjectTemplate/UI-CustomDialog.wxs) in the code of my open source project ISWIX.

Comment: <TextStyle Id="DlgTitleFont" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8"
Bold="yes"/>
<Dialog Id="InstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="no">
<Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
<Text>{\DlgTitleFont}Ready to Install</Text>
</Control>
<Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install">
<Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
</Control>
</Dialog>
<InstallUISequence>
<Show Dialog="InstallDlg" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>